# How to declare App-level variable for being used by all the components

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I have this App with a Firestore db variable, I'm currently passing the db through the widgets' constructor. Is there any way my widget can get the App's db variable without declaring a properties for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare such a variable anywhere outside a class or function (top-level).
You make the shared variable available by importing the file that contains it.

Another way are static fields in classes.
You also need to import the library that contains the class and access it with the classname as prefix.

*shared_var.dart*

```
String globalFoo = 'foo';

class Global {
  static bar = 'bar';
}
```

*somewhere.dart*

```
import 'package:my_package/shared_var.dart';

void foo() {
  print(globalFoo);
}

void bar() {
  print(Global.bar);
}
```

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:my_package/somewhere.dart';

void main() {
  foo();
}
```